# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Diffamierung" und "Diskreditierung"?

Tags: difference

Beim Lesen bin ich auf das Wort *diffamieren* gestoßen und habe dessen Definition nachgeschlagen.

> jemanden in seinem Ansehen schädigen, ihn herabsetzen, oder ihn in Verruf bringen
>   [Quelle: Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/diffamieren)

Zugleich kam mir das Wort *diskreditieren* in den Sinn.

> in Misskredit bringen, in Verruf bringen
>   [Quelle: Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/diskreditieren)

Beide Wörter scheinen den selben Sachverhalt zu beschreiben, jedoch sind sie nicht als Synonyme gelistet.

Folgt daraus nun ein kleiner Unterschied oder können sie, wie von mir angenommen, einfach synonym verwendet werden?

Comment: Meinem Sprachgefühl nach ist diskreditieren auch subtiler und indirekter als diffamieren und denunzieren, hat also eine "intrigante" Komponente. Stringent begründen kann ich das aber nicht.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dies ist ein kniffliges Paar und ich denke gerne noch etwas mehr darüber nach; einige wichtigen Unterschiede kann ich jedoch gleich nennen.

### *Diskreditieren*

beschreibt eine Handlung die **das Vertrauen** in etwas oder jemanden untergräbt. Obwohl dies meist absichtlich und oft aus Bosheit geschieht, sind beide Faktoren nicht notwendig. So kann man sogar sich selbst diskreditieren:

> Durch seine widerlichen rassistischen Aussagen über Asiaten, diskreditierte er sich als Mitglied des Rates.

Es ist nicht daran zu denken, hier "diffamieren" einzusetzen.

### *Diffamieren*

beschreibt meines Erachtens stets eine verwerfliche, bösartige Handlung. Es sollte wohl nicht reflexiv in Erscheinung treten. Wie in einer anderen Antwort richtig aufgezeigt, richtet sich das diffamieren per Definitionem gegen **das Ansehen** des Anderen.

> Hatte er zu Lebzeiten des Toten danach getrachtet diesen zu diskreditieren und ihn letztlich um seine Stellung zu bringen, so genoß er es nun ihn als Päderasten zu diffamieren und sein Andenken zu schänden, wo er es nur vermochte.

Comment: Der Tendenz stimme ich zu, aber nicht der Wertung, dass die Diffamierung verwerflich sein muss. Sie muss absichtsvoll nachteilig für den Diffamierten sein aber der, der die Diffamierung tätigt, bewertet sie natürlich positiv - sonst würde er es ja lassen.

Comment: @userunknown ein solcher Begriff wäre sinnvoll, meines Erachtens beinhaltet "diffamieren" jedoch eindeutig eine negative Wertung. Anders gesagt, besagter Diffamierender würde sich selbst nicht so nennen.

Comment: a) Soll sich ein Diffamierer nicht selbst so nennen, sondern den Vorgang. b)  Würdest Du Ähnliches auch von Denunziation denken? "Sie gibt sich nicht mehr als Selbstzweck, sondern nur noch als Mittel. Ihr wesentliches Pathos ist die Indignation, ihre wesentliche Arbeit die Denunziation." - Karl Marx, Einl. zur Kritik der Hegelschen Rechstphilosophie, http://www.mlwerke.de/me/me01/me01_378.htm Nicht jeder Diffamierer ist auch ein Heuchler.

Comment: @userunknown ich verstehe nicht ganz, worauf Sie hinaus möchten . Ich glaube es fehlt ein Teil ihres Kommentars. Ich bin nicht sicher, wie es sich mit "denunzieren" verhielte. Es wurde im EU Parlament im rechtlichen Kontext reflexiv verwandt.  Ich will mal über der Frage schlafen, ob dies richtig war...

Answer (score 8):

Die beiden Begriffe sind sich sehr ähnlich, und wahrscheinlich im täglich deutschen Sprachgebrauch (wo sie außerhalb der Politik, in deren Umfeld sie sehr deckungsgleich sind, nicht so sehr auftreten) Synonyme.

Um den Unterschied herauszuarbeiten, muss man wohl in die Originalsprache kucken:

**Diskreditieren** enthält den Wortstamm "credere" (glauben) und betrifft damit die *Glaubwürdigkeit* einer  bzw. das *Vertrauen* in die Person, der geschadet wird.

**Diffamieren** enthält "fama", also "was die Leute reden", also den *Ruf* der Person, zu deren Nachteil das geschieht.

Die Frage kann also umformuliert werden zu "was ist der Unterschied zwischen **Ruf** und **Glaubwürdigkeit**?". - Der "schlechte Ruf" kann in allem Möglichen begründet sein, die schlechte Glaubwürdigkeit nur in der (vermeintlichen) Ehrlichkeit der Person.

Ob die beiden Worte tatsächlich auch immer in dieser Trennschärfe verwendet werden, wage ich zu bezweifeln.

Comment: Mir kommt zusätzlich noch "denunzieren" in den Sinn. Zugegeben, es ist nochmal anders, aber ich assoziiere das mehr mit "diffamieren" als mit "diskreditieren". Bei "denunzieren" und "diffamieren" schwingt für mich mit, dass jemand _ungeachtet des Wahrheitsgehalts_ der Anschuldigung in Verruf gebracht wird. Bei einer Diskreditierung würde ich eher unterstellen, dass die Anschuldigung an sich stimmt. Das geht zumindest in die gleiche Richtung wie Deine Antwort, wenn ich Dich recht verstehe.

Comment: For me, there's also the factor of the intention and credibility of the accuser. Diffamieren can be a try to discredit someone, and if successful, the target is diskreditiert (the general public agrees and views the target more negatively). If the attempt fails, it's just an 'empty' attack and the target might be seen as the victim.